# Android Design Support Library Navigation-view Customization

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport, android-navigationview

I have a couple of questions about the new navigation view.

**1)** Scrolling the navigation view scrolls the whole view but I just want the header to stay at it's place and the navigation item to scroll.

[image]

**2)** To implement dividers b/w navigation items, I can do something like this:

```
<item
android:id="@+id/navigation_subheader"
android:title="@string/navigation_subheader">
<menu>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_sub_item_1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"
        android:title="@string/navigation_sub_item_1"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_sub_item_2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"
        android:title="@string/navigation_sub_item_2"/>
</menu>
</item>
```

But It does not work without the subheader. I tried to give it an blank string but that just leaves a vertical blank space instead of the subheader. I need the navigation item groups separated by dividers but without the subheaders.

**3)** Manipulating the navigation items dynamically. Before this, I used to use vertical list view as navigation item. Where I'd just set the visibility to gone of whichever navigation item I didn't want. How can I dynamically change the navigation items?

Comment: Create your own view, with linear layout and listview at the bottom, which will only be scrollable.

Comment: I was using that. But since this is out, I was wondering If that's possible in NavigationView

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to achieve what you want. Because NavigationView will not give much flexibility ..

Comment: But you can solve the problem .. Just include header layout and below header take the `listview` and this both should be nest in `NavigationView`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) Scrolling the navigation view scrolls the whole view but I just want the >header to stay at it's place and the navigation item to scroll.

You can't obtain it with the current `NavigationView`. It follows the Material guidelines. If you would like this kind of pattern you have to use a custom view.

> 2) To implement dividers b/w navigation items, I can do something like this:

You can use the standard `NavigationView` defining a menu like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:id="@+id/group1" android:checkableBehavior="single" id>
       //items of group1
    </group>

    <group android:id="@+id/group2" android:checkableBehavior="single" id>
       //items of group2
    </group>
</menu>
```

It is important to give an unique id to each group.

> 3) Manipulating the navigation items dynamically

You can use something like:

```
navigationview.getMenu().findItem(R.id.drawer_item_xxx).setVisible(xxx);
```

Comment: Thanks !! It works. I had tried with group but didn't think id would be required. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

*1) Scrolling the navigation view scrolls the whole view but I just want the >header to stay at it's place and the navigation item to scroll.*

Since NavigationView is a FrameLayout we can add a ListView as a child and don't forget to delete app:menu attribute in the NavigationView then You'll get the desired behavior.